# How to use RDBMS for design event sourcing?

Tags: database, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I want to use the event sourcing in a real project.

I found the following structure:

```
Table Events:
    Id [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    TimeStamp [datetime] NOT NULL,
    Name [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    Version [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    EventSourceId [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    Sequence [bigint], 
    Data [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
```

But my problem is I don't know if this table is for my whole project or do I have to create an event table for each domain aggregation?

Comment: First I would suggest to use separate table with proper relation to store data; To identify how to better "shard" you need to answer few questions before:

1) what is aproximate number of events be stored per hour/day/week/year
2) how would you use this data after?
3) why do you wanna to have event sourcing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my problem is I don't know if this table is for my whole project or do I have to create an event table for each domain aggregation?

The folks at [Message DB](https://github.com/message-db/message-db) recommend using a single table for all messages.

Note that this is in Postgres; they aren't making any claims about how you should implement an event store in other relational data models.  The message db design takes advantages of locking capabilities available in Postgres that may not be universal.

I'd encourage you to find an "out of the box" store like message-db, rather than trying to roll your own.  But if you can't find something suitable, then looking at the design of message db, and Jon Oliver's [CQRS event store](https://blog.jonathanoliver.com/cqrs-event-store/) notes, may help you to avoid some of the more common mistakes.

Comment: thanks for you answer. If we store them all in one table, a lot of data from the whole system is gathered together and it is very difficult to use this data, but in the design of a simple database (without event sourcing), we have many tables with separate data. That data can be easily used. We use CQRS to run faster queries, but as far as I know, reliable data is only available in event store db, so for example, if our reading models are deleted, it will be difficult to rebuild it. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: It's just another table; there's no rule against updating multiple tables within the same RDBMS transaction.